# Why can my array "Not be resolved to a variable"?

Tags: java, arrays

```
static void createArray(String function) {

 int j = 10;
 int results[]; 
 results = new int[j+1];

for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {

    String stringI = Integer.toString(i);
    int sum = 0;
    function = function.replace("X",stringI);
    String[] Pluses = function.split("\\+");

    for (String multString: Pluses) {

    String[] mults = multString.split("\\*");
        int multAcc = 1;
    for (String num: mults)
        {
        multAcc *= Integer.parseInt(num);
        }
        sum = sum + multAcc;

        }
        results[i] = sum;   
    }
}

public static void main (String args[]) {
```

Hello, exscuse me for bad formatting, this is my first post on Stackoverflow.

When compiling I encounter an error that says that "results cannot be resolved to a variable".
The code is supposed to create an array containing the integer values of the first 10 values of a function that i've written into the console.

```
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter function");

    String function = myScanner.nextLine();
    createArray(function);
    System.out.println(Arrays.ToString(results));

    myScanner.close();
    }
```

Comment: `results` is currently only in the scope of the `createArray` method, it isn't known from other methods.

Comment: Make `results` a static variable of your class, rather than a local variable. Or better alternative: Make `createArray` return `results` instead of void.

Comment: Instead of returning nothing (void), your method should return the results.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables inside a `{ ... }` are not accessible outside.

```
static int[] createArray(String function) {
    int j = 10;
    int[] results = new int[j+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        String stringI = Integer.toString(i);
        int sum = 0;
        function = function.replace("X", stringI);
        String[] pluses = function.split("\\+");

        for (String multString: pluses) {

            String[] mults = multString.split("\\*");
            int multAcc = 1;
            for (String num: mults)
            {
                multAcc *= Integer.parseInt(num);
            }
            sum += multAcc;

        }
        results[i] = sum;
    }
    return results;
}

    int[] array = createArray(function);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Let the function return the array, and use a new variable at the call.

The above probably will not do what you intended:

- `replace` replaces all occurrences of the letter X. A second variable?

Comment: No, X comes from me entering functions such as 3*X+5 into the panel. I want to replace X with say 4 for the fourth value of the function. @Joop

Comment: `String filled = function.replace(...); String[] pluses = filled.split("\\+");` I would think, as otherwise for i>0 the function of i=0 is taken. (No longer an X in function)

Answer (score 1):

**results** is local variable inside **createArray()** method. In order to solve this issue you can do either of following:

1. Declare results as **static member** in class
2. Return array of integer from **createArray()** method.